# Mongodb $lookup in Spring data mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm a new Mongodb and I have a problem with $lookup with java spring.

I would like to use this shell in Spring data

```
db.NewFeed.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {username : "user001"}
    },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "NewfeedContent",
          localField: "content.contentId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "NewfeedContent"
        }
   }
])
```

I found on Google but no answer yet.

Comment: is there any error? can you explain what is not working ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not every "new" feature makes it immediately into abstraction layers such as [spring-mongo](/questions/tagged/spring-mongo).

So instead, all you need do is define a class that uses the `AggregationOperation` interface, which will instead take a BSON Object specified directly as it's content:

```
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your aggregation like this:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(
        Criteria.where("username").is("user001")
    ),
    new CustomAggregationOperation(
        new BasicDBObject(
            "$lookup",
            new BasicDBObject("from", "NewFeedContent")
                .append("localField","content.contentId")
                .append("foreignField", "_id")
                .append("as", "NewFeedContent")
        )
    )
)
```

Which shows the custom class mixed with the built in `match()` pipeline helper.

All that happens underneath each helper is that they serialize to a BSON representation such as with `DBObject` anyway. So the constructor here just takes the object directly, and returns it directly from `.toDBObject()`, which is the standard method on the interface that will be called when serializing the pipline contents.

Comment: Spring Data Mongo now supports lookup operations https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.x and spring-data-mongodb 2.0, the DBObject has been replaced with Document. You have also to replace toDBObject() with toDocument().
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.2-0-0

Answer (score 24):

Joining Two Collections with Spring Data MongoDB

Employee Class

```
class Employee {
    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private String dept_id;
}
```

Department Class

```
class Department {
    private String _id;
    private String dept_name;
}
```

Employee Result Class

```
public class EmpDeptResult {

    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private List<Object> departments;
}
```

EmployeeService Class

```
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeService.class);

    public void lookupOperation(){
    LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                        .from("Department")
                        .localField("dept_id")
                        .foreignField("_id")
                        .as("departments");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is("1")) , lookupOperation);
        List<EmpDeptResult> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Employee", EmpDeptResult.class).getMappedResults();
        LOGGER.info("Obj Size " +results.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to join on multiple fields is there a way ?

Comment: its possible paginate the result?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example:

Collection **posts**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a198074ed31adaf5d79fe8a"),
"title" : "Post 1",
"authors" : [1, 2]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a198074ed31adaf5d79fe8d"),
"title" : "Post 2",
"authors" : [2]
}
```

Collection **users**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a18b483ed31ada08fd6ed82"),
"userId" : 1,
"name" : "Vinod Kumar"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a18b483ed31ada08fd6ed83"),
"userId" : 2,
"name" : "Jim Hazel"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a18b483ed31ada08fd6ed84"),
"userId" : 3,
"name" : "Alex Wong"
}
```

Mongodb query with lookup and match

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "authors",
      as: "post"
    }
  },
  {
     $match: { "post": { $ne: [] } }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Spring Mongoopration syntax

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
            from("posts").
            localField("userid").
            foreignField("authors").
            as("post");

AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("post").size(1));


Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation, match);

List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "users", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 8):

Its too late to answer this, but it might helps other who are facing the same issue. 
If you are using spring-boot-data-mongodb-2.0 or above version then there is a easy way to implement this.

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("username").is("user001")));
AggregationOperation query = Aggregation.lookup("NewfeedContent", "content.contentId", "_id", "NewfeedContent");
// If you want to unwind
//AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("Patient");
Aggregation agr = Aggregation.newAggregation(query, match, unwind);
AggregationResults<Document> result = springTemplate.aggregate(agr, "CollectionName", Document.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use below to join 3 Collections

```java
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "DBname" );

BasicDBObject query = BasicDBObject.parse("{$match:{_id:61188}},\n" +
        "   {\n" +
        "     $lookup:\n" +
        "       {\n" +
        "         from: \"CustomerDetails\",\n" +
        "         localField: \"supplierId\",\n" +
        "         foreignField: \"supplierId\",\n" +
        "         as: \"newfield\"\n" +
        "       }\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "  ,  {\n" +
        "     $lookup:\n" +
        "       {\n" +
        "         from: \"ItemDetails\",\n" +
        "         localField: \"supplierId\",\n" +
        "         foreignField: \"supplierId\",\n" +
        "         as: \"newfield\"\n" +
        "       }\n" +
        "  }");

AggregationOutput dumps = db.getCollection("HeaderInfo").aggregate(query);

System.out.println("result="+dumps.results());
```

Comment: Not able to send two $lookup objects in parse method, its considering only one lookup object.  please help