# $lookup aggregation function in springboot using MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

```
db.cqm.aggregate(
    {
      $match:{node:"ERP-APPLICATION"}},
      {
        $lookup:
       {
          from: "cqm",
          localField: "depends_on.node",
          foreignField: "node",
          as: "depends_on_hardware"
       }
    },
    {
      $lookup:
      {
       from: "cqm",
       localField: "depends_on_hardware.depends_on.node",
       foreignField: "node",
       as: "depends_on_hardware_server"
      }
    }).pretty()
```

Above is $lookup used in MongoDB. How can I implement this in springboot by using MongoTemplate.

Comment: Here is post with answers (using MongoTemplate): [Mongodb $lookup in Spring data mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145229/mongodb-lookup-in-spring-data-mongo).